# Ошибка при создании меню

Tags: android, android-menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_utem_new_crime"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:title="@string/new_crime"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        />
```

Не могу понять в чем же ошибка:

> Should use `app:showAsAction` with appcompat library with `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
>
> When using the appcompat library, menu resources should refer to the `showAsAction` in the `app:` namespace, not the `android:` namespace.
>
> Similarly, when **not** using the appcompat library, you should be using the `android:showAsAction` attribute.

Вот скриншот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как можно исправить ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `app` вместо `android`

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

Comment: да помогло! Ошибки больше нет !
А в чем разница? И почему выбрасывает ошибку ?

Comment: Вам IDE очень красиво подсказывает почему, вкратце это связано из-за того что вы используете библиотеку AppCompat

Comment: последний вопрос:
Почему может не отображаться меню на OptionBar (android 4.2.2) ?  Но при нажатии на физическую  клавишу - меню отображается !
Можно ли как-то сделать чтобы оно было в любом случаи ?

Comment: те не отображается в toolbar-е ?? скиньте код, я недавно решал задачу чтоб убрать, икону меню с ActionBar, очень интересно )

Comment: Я читал, что в некоторых смартфонах, которых есть физическая кнопка опций - в тулбаре (в виде трех точек) меню не будет отображаться !! Или можно как -то это настраивать ??? (это не проект. Просто по этому примеру делал  http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/menu.php